# Receive array in flutter from one page to another

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I want to receive hole array list in flutter. I know how to get one by one but I want to receive hole array list from arguments in flutter

Here I am sending list

```
  builder: (context) =>ADDToCART(),settings: RouteSettings(arguments: Items.cartitems)),
```

cartitems is a list where all items added in a cart
I can receive it like (Create  static list) but I need a professional method

Send and receive array in flutter  from one page to another

Receiving code is

```
 Object? cartitems=ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `as` operator. Assuming the value `Items.cartItems` is of type `List<Item>`, you could do:

```dart
List<Item> cartItems = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as List<Item>;
```

That will not throw any exception as long as Dart can properly cast the object you are passing as an argument to a `List<Item>`. If, for instance, you were to pass any other class or data structure, it would throw an exception.